# Creating ORACLE PL/SQL store procedures with different kind of AND conditions

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to create a Oracle query for example

```
select * from emp where emp_id=i_emp_id and emp_nm=i_emp_nm and emp_dpt=i_emp_dpt
```

if all the three inputs are not null it should function like

```
select * from emp where emp_id=i_emp_id and emp_nm=i_emp_nm and emp_dpt=i_emp_dpt
```

if i pass i_emp_id as null then the query should function like

```
select * from emp where emp_nm=i_emp_nm and emp_dpt=i_emp_dpt
```

if i pass i_emp_id as null and i_emp_dpt as null then the query should function like

```
select * from emp where emp_nm=i_emp_nm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle different permutations of input variables is to assemble the query dynamically.  The following example will produce a query which performs well and handles NULL values neatly so as to return the correct result.

```
create or replace function get_dyn_emps
   (i_empno in emp.empno%type
    ,  i_ename in emp.ename%type
    , i_deptno in emp.deptno%type)
    return sys_refcursor
is
    rc sys_refcursor;
    stmt varchar2(32767);
begin
    stmt := 'select * from emp where 1=1';
    if i_empno is not null
    then
        stmt := stmt||' and empno = :p_empno';
    else
        stmt := stmt||' and (1=1 or :p_empno is null)';
    end if;
    if i_ename is not null
    then
        stmt := stmt||' and ename = :p_ename';
    else
        stmt := stmt||' and (1=1 or :p_ename is null)';
    end if;        
    if i_deptno is not null
    then
        stmt := stmt||' and deptno = :p_deptno';
    else
        stmt := stmt||' and (1=1 or :p_deptno is null)';
    end if;

    open rc for stmt 
        using i_empno, i_ename , i_deptno;
    return rc;
end get_dyn_emps;
/
```

---

This may seem like a long-winded solution compared to the currently-accepted answer, but here's why it is the better approach: *it returns the correct answer*.

In deparment 40 there is an employee with no name:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec :rc := get_dyn_emps(null, null, 40)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

  EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM    DEPTNO
------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------
   8101                                 03-DEC-10                              40

SQL>
```

If I implement the apparently neater DECODE() solution ...

```
create or replace function get_fix_emps
   (i_empno in emp.empno%type
    ,  i_ename in emp.ename%type
    , i_deptno in emp.deptno%type)
    return sys_refcursor
is
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for 
        SELECT * FROM emp 
         WHERE empno = DECODE(NVL(i_empno,0), 0, empno, i_empno)
           AND ename = DECODE(NVL(i_ename,'X'), 'X', ename, i_ename) 
           AND deptno = DECODE(NVL(i_deptno,0), 0, deptno, i_deptno);
    return rc;
end get_fix_emps;
/
```

... this is what happens:

```
SQL> exec :rc := get_fix_emps(null, null, 40)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Because NULL does not ever equal NULL, which is what `ename = DECODE(NVL(i_ename,'X'), 'X', ename, i_ename)` evaluates to in this case.

Comment: Currently i am automating the process of creating store procedure in oracle  i just need a generalised query to select values from a table based on the given input..

Comment: @Aravind - as the OP you are allowed to accept whatever answer meets your needs.  However, for the benefit of other seekers who find this thread through Google or whatever, I have to point out that the DECODE() solution is sub-optimal and will produce the wrong results in certain scenarios.  Not yours perhaps, but there is a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

As I did in my applications, you can achieve this functionality by simply using NVL and DECODE functions.

```
SELECT * FROM emp 
 WHERE emp_id = DECODE(NVL(i_emp_id,0), 0, emp_id, i_emp_id)
   AND emp_nm = DECODE(NVL(i_emp_nm,0), 0, emp_nm, i_emp_nm) 
   AND emp_dpt = DECODE(NVL(i_emp_dpt,'X'), 'X', emp_dpt, i_emp_dpt)
```

If `i_emp_id` is null than it will match with current value so all records will match otherwise only record which matches `i_emp_id` will return. Same applies to `emp_nm` and `emp_dpt`.

Comment: You may get performance issues as the query cannot readily use indexes with such a construct. Sometimes the IF..ELSIF...ELSE..END IF; is a better option

Comment: Yeh I know but this approach I used mostly with Oracle Reports where i've to based report on certain criteria.

Comment: This answer will produce the wrong results when the passed parameter is null and the column it maps to contains nulls.  See my answer for a demonstration.